# Sharing Sidekiq between two apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am looking for a solution for communicating between two Rails app. I have two servers, one for web, and one for analytics. When an user signs up via web server, this server needs to notify analytic server to create some result (which may take a few minutes), then get the result from it.

Is it possible to have a Sidekiq server that can access to two servers at the same time (without setting up API)? How should I go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sidekiq uses [Redis](http://redis.io/) to store the jobs. You could have a shared redis database where you:

- push data into redis from one app
- pull data from redis from one other app

Comment: Thanks Pierre. It seems to be a great solution. Just want to make sure I understand you correctly: I can have Sidekiq installed in both web server and backend server. Then, on the front-end, I configure Sidekiq to point to Redis database server in the backend server. I start Rails backend server only. Then, front-end Sidekiq can write into backend Sidekiq (communicating via Redis).

Comment: Yes this should work. Sidekiq allows you to specify a custom Redis connection. Simply specify the same one (same domain, same port) for all your applications.

Comment: old question but I have 2 different apps (different codebases).  Both will have their own sidekiq instances.  They will use a shared redis instance.  If I schedule a job on an app, I want it to run on that app only.  Could the the other app try and pick the job up from redis?  If so how can i prevent this?

Comment: @user3437721, did you find a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes its possible. You can have shared redis database for both server. In your initializers/sidekiq.rb file,

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0', namespace: "sidekiq_app_name_#{Rails.env}" }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0', namespace: "sidekiq_app_name_#{Rails.env}" }
end
```

Comment: Now you need to add redis-namespace gem. It's not a dependency of sidekiq anymore.
https://github.com/resque/redis-namespace

Comment: Just as a comment, It looks like `namespace` is not recommended. 

- https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/3330df0ee37cfd3e0cd3ef01e3e66b584b99d488/4.0-Upgrade.md#whats-new

- https://www.mikeperham.com/2015/09/24/storing-data-with-redis/#namespaces